# Conversion of if/else based JSON by using Jolt

Tags: json, apache-nifi, transformation, jolt

I have two following json input and i want to convert it into expected output by jolt

***input - 1***

```json
{
  "alert_array": {
    "alerts": [
      {
        "id": "1234",
        "data": {
          "parameter": [
            {
              "key": "level",
              "value": "93.5"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

***input - 2***

```json
{
  "alert_array": {
    "alerts": [
      {
        "id": "1234",
        "data": {}
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

***expected output - 1***

```json
{
  "alertArray": [
    {
      "id": "1234",
      "properties": [
        {
          "key": "level",
          "value": "93.5"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

***expected output - 2***

```json
{
  "alertArray": [
    {
      "id": "1234",
      "properties": []
    }
  ]
}
```

In ***input-1 data contain some parameter but in input-2 data object is blank***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **default** transformation along with **shift** transformations

in order to add **`"properties": []`** for the empty case of **"data"** object for the both of the input

JSON values such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "alerts": {
          "*": {
            "id": "alertArray.&",
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "*": {
                  "id": "alertArray.properties[&1].key",
                  "*": "alertArray.properties[&1].&"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "properties": []
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "&[]"
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** for the **first** case :

[image]

the ***demo*** for the **second** case :

[image]

If there was no such need(*to fill up for the "data"*), then the following single spec would be sufficient :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "alerts": {
          "*": {
            "id": "alertArray[&1].&",
            "*": {
              "*": {
                "*": {
                  "id": "alertArray[&4].properties[&1].key",
                  "*": "alertArray[&4].properties[&1].&"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi Barbaros Thanks for your response . For second input not getting desire output . For blank object("data" : {}) not getting desire output ("properties" :[])

Comment: Sorry there was some change in input and output i have change it now

Comment: I am facing issue with only data object . if data is blank then output should be ("properties" :[]) otherwise all the parameter data will be assign to the properties

Comment: I can not use Frist one . I can use only shift operation

Comment: @Neeraj Have you able to check out the added demoes which were taken from the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ ?